# How can I make initial app test runs in my device?

Tags: flutter

The test should run in the device as in the next video, insted of the headless test as comes in default

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ms02pJ9icup7nRDt1axh050WbFbiMDqd/view?usp=sharing

How can I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run an iOS simulator using the following commands on a mac terminal :
open -a simulator
flutter run
You can run an android emulator on mac or windows using following commands in terminal :
flutter emulator --launch

Incase you don't know emulator id, run the following command before the above one

flutter emulators

Alternatively run debug version of the app on your physical device that has developer tools  turned on.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question I asked for